# Query error: No tables used in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

```
*In my model send_credentials_user*
public function send_credentials_user($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $user = $query->row();
        log_message('error',$user);
    }
    else return FALSE;
}
```

Why i am unable to query the database.I am using proper table name.But i am still getting the same error.

Comment: Is everything okay with configs? Do another queries run?

Comment: yes.@DannyChernyavsky

Comment: Please, try: `var_dump($this->db->last_query());` after `$query = $this->db->get();`. And after var_dumping try this query instantly in your DB (eg using phpmyadmin).

Comment: Still same error @DannyChernyavsky

Comment: Hm, you mean CI's database error, without any different output (var_dump) ?

Comment: can you explain which type of error you got?

Comment: No.. i didn't get any output @DannyChernyavsky

Comment: When i use log_message i am getting No tables used error.Actually Query is not properly executing here.I am not getting any data @DannyChernyavsky

Comment: Which version of CodeIgniter are you using?

Comment: I don't know. Where can i find this.@MonkeyZeus

Comment: I am honestly not sure lol. Whenever I do a CodeIgniter project I like to use this path format `/codeigniter/2.1.4/myApplicationName/controllers or models or views` etc...

Comment: Here i am missing return $user; after $user = $query->row();.Now i can get the query result.Thank you everyone who helped me.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$query = $this->db->get('users');
```

**UPDATE**

```
public function send_credentials_user($id){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('id', $id);

$query = $this->db->get('users');

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    $user = $query->row();
    log_message('error',$user);
}
else return FALSE;
}
```

This will work

Comment: I am not getting query result

Comment: Send me result of
var_dump($this->db->last_query());

Comment: I did not see var_dump result.When i use log_message it shows no tables used error

Comment: use var_dump($query);die;

Comment: where i can that output